# CSS custom settings

Tags: python, html, css, design-patterns

when I compile my .scss to .css, sass wil automaticly make this:

```
Main.scss
.input-section ...{
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

To Main.scss
.input-section ...{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

This may sound good for the browsers at first, but it only causes errors.
The erros in the screenhot:

```
Error processing the value for 'CLASS_NAME'.  Declaration ignored.
```

[image]

Is there any way to stop the automatic generation of browser help for each element/class?
Here a second screenshot how it compiles in my VsCode
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonably normal for browsers to output warning messages for declarations they don't understand, but the expected behaviour will be that they ignore that line and carry on, thus finding a line that they do understand.

I don't think you should be looking to avoid this, it's normal.

For example, when a browser doesn't understand `-webkit-box` it skips the line and find `-ms-flexbox` and then uses this value. You get a warning about the first line, but you get the correct behaviour.

You could get rid of the warning by removing `-webkit-box`, but you then have unexpected behaviour in WebKit, even though you fixed the other browsers.